# NULL bufferedImage from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java

I'm trying to read this POST request and extract the image. Then save it to disk, but the buffered image is null

Here is the code (the main part):

```
private void handleImage(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{


        InputStream inStream = request.getInputStream();

        byte[] body = IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream);

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(body);
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);

        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", new File(
                "hi.png"));
```

Comment: What is the application server that you are using?

Comment: This is a Jetty server receiving a POST request

Comment: You already have an `InputStream` from `request.getInputStream()`. You don't need to read that into a byte array and then construct *another* `InputStream.` Just do `ImageIO.read(request.getInputStream()).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using a fancy mechanism like sending screen shots from flash to server, the form you use to send the image is probably multipart/form-data.
In this case the input stream does not hold only the binary image information, it's multi-part encoded so also has some information related to file, as well as other form elements.
Here is a sample output of the input stream. When you try to create an image from that stream, it won't be able to parse because of the multi-part seperators.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryrD6PkQsxtK9sZGBB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"; filename="test.png"
Content-Type: image/png

[binarydata]
```

Apache commons has one library to parse multi-part form data that you can use.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/